# Routes pagination Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, routes, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3 and I want to paginate my users.
However when I click on the second page, the URL looks like `/users?page=2` and I expect : `/users/2`.

I created this route in routes.php :

```
$routes->connect('/users/:page', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'], ['page' => '[0-9]+']);
```

And in Users/index.ctp before the "prev" button I put :

```
<?php
      $this->Paginator->options([
              'url' => [
              'controller' => 'users',
              'action' => 'index'
          ]
      ]);
 ?>
```

Now when I click on page 2 for example, `/users/2` opens and I got this error message (RuntimeException) :

```
Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate.
```

Did I miss something or where I made a mistake ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with routes or the usage of the helper. Please show your controller code, that is the place where the problem lies

Comment: My users controller was generated with cake bake command. So my index method looks like this : `$this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users)); $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);`

Comment: can you do a `debug($this->Users)` before calling paginate? I think in your case `$this->Users` is `false` or an empty array for some reason.

Comment: The array is not empty and I got this object : 
`object(App\Model\Table\UsersTable) {

 'registryAlias' => 'Users',
 'table' => 'users',
 'alias' => 'Users',
 'entityClass' => 'App\Model\Entity\User',
 'associations' => [],
 'behaviors' => [],
 'defaultConnection' => 'default',
 'connectionName' => 'default'

}`

Comment: Are you calling paginate somewhere else? It would be nice to see the full stack trace of the error you are getting

Comment: You can see stack trace with the error into this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/whbv9p18a59dkl8/error.png?dl=0

Comment: No idea, then... Try to go to the `paginate()` method in the controller class and debug the parameters it is getting. For some reason it is getting an empty variable

Comment: Actually I was wrong `$this->Users` return `false` but I don't know why

Comment: The problem well comes to the $this->Users that return false

Comment: Can you gist your full controller class?

Comment: Here is my UsersController : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e88da6f8201da821846

Comment: first in your action index there is no param for page !
second thing did it works without this route ?
finally try to add in your action index the param $page and add to the routerthis ['pass' => 'page']

Answer (score 0):

The PaginatorHelper has built in the url format, i.e. to use ?page=n. It will also do sorting such as users?page=2&sort=user_id&direction=asc.  Your format of /users/{page} does not handle sorting.

If your REALLY want to stick to /users/{page} you'll have to override PaginatorHelper.

Comment: For the moment I don't want to handle users sort.
I'll see to override PaginatorHelper but I'm not really comfortable in Cakephp overriding. I'll try to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this 
in side your controller with paginator component . It works for me

```
$this->Paginator->paginate('Users')
```

for custom url`enter code here`
u need to implement index action as

```
public function index($page = null){
$this->Paginator->settings = ['limit' => 15, 'page' => $page];
$this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate('Users'));
}
```